# Можно ли сменить бинд кнопки мышки (JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, скрипт, frontend

Есть ссылка, самая обычная. Допустим:

```
<a href="link.html" target="_blank">Some text</a>
```

Можно ли сделать что бы при нажатии левой кнопкой мышки, ссылка открывалась командой нажатие на колесико?

Я бы не поднимал этот вопрос если бы не наткнулся на "читалку" клика:
https://jsfiddle.net/dscshmg4/5/

Смотреть, наблюдать можно - может и влиять можно.

```
document.getElementById('mouse-click').onmousedown = function(e) {
if (e.which == 1) {this.innerHTML = "Была нажата левая кнопка мыши"}
if (e.which == 2) {this.innerHTML = "Было нажато колёсико мыши"}
if (e.which == 3) {this.innerHTML = "Была нажата правая кнопка мыши"} 
}
```

**Спасибо**

Comment: А зачем? Может вам нужен атрибут target?

Comment: Мои попытки "имитации событий" пару лет назад успехом не закончились. Я хотел симитировать нажатие вниз на списке <select>, что б тот раскрылся при наведении мышью.

Comment: за таргет вкурсе. тут особенности свои есть. тут не иммитация в классике нужна, а подмена

Comment: Подменять событие скорее всего запрещено. Можно прервать текущее, и создать новое [fireEvent](https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events). Если событие знаете кто обработает дальше - можно подменить класс но думаю тогда врядли бы вопрос был.

Comment: но вопрос все же. Ваша мысль имеет продолжение? :)

Comment: Так чего вы в итоге хотите добиться?

Comment: Я понял, вы хотите кликнуть, тогда почему просто не вызвать клик `button.click()` из события по клику скролом? *можно ли сменить бинд*  - загадочно, я понял как подменить событие.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не поднимал этот вопрос если бы не наткнулся на "читалку" клика:
https://jsfiddle.net/dscshmg4/5/

Смотреть, наблюдать можно - может и влиять можно.

```
document.getElementById('mouse-click').onmousedown = function(e) {
if (e.which == 1) {this.innerHTML = "Была нажата левая кнопка мыши"}
if (e.which == 2) {this.innerHTML = "Было нажато колёсико мыши"}
if (e.which == 3) {this.innerHTML = "Была нажата правая кнопка мыши"} 
}
```

Comment: Если это дополнение к вопросу - то добавьте это в секцию вопрос.

Comment: есть, добавил...